# yii-rights module table representation

Tags: php, authentication, yii, yii-extensions

I've installed the [yii-rights](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/rights/) module. I'm trying to understand what each table the module created does. It looks to me that

- tbl_authitem: stores the contents for roles, tasks and operations.
- tbl_authitemchild: stores the relationship between roles, tasks and operations.
- tbl_authassignment: stores the assignment of roles, tasks and operations to users.

However, I've no idea what the table tbl_rights does. Can anybody shed some light on that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first three tables are the standard tables of the Yii RBAC. "Rights" is an internal table of the Rights module. Apparently it logs the weight of items in the interface, but whenever I used Rights, it always stayed empty. It should not have any effect on managing authorization, so you can ignore it.